# Hathcher's exposition of Homotopy Extension Property

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am having a ton of problems with a short section from Hatcher on p 14.  Specifically, the 7-1/2 lines after the proposition on mid-page make no sense to me.
He indicates that he is about to give an implication of the proposition, but instead just restates half of the proposition.

Or is he proving the foregoing proposition? If so, how can he use the identity map to prove anything, since that is a special case?  Furthermore, what he then calls the converse does not seem to be the actual converse of what he just showed.

I think my problem is more the English, and misunderstanding what he's trying to do, rather than the math.

Comment: can you tell explicitly, what is the problem?? Or atleast write down the section and indicate your doubts

Comment: Here's what he says:

Comment: Here's what Hatcher says on p14:  "A pair (X,A) has the homotopy extension property if and only if X x {0} U A x I is a retract of X x I."   Then he goes on to say "For one implication, the homotopy extension property for (X,A) implies that the identity map X x {0} U A x I -> X x {0} U A x I extends to a map X x I -> X x {0} U A x I, so X x {0} U A x I is a retract of X x I."  My problem is that the "implication" (the second sentence) is not an implication at all, but in the end, simply restates the conclusion of his first statement. Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems to me that his "one implication" is a short proof that "A pair $(X,A)$"has the homotopy extension property" implies that $X\times\{0\}\cup A\times I$ is a retract of $X\times I$.